# Need script to edit MS word document in an automated manner

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I'm working on data entry. I typed 500 pages but I did a mistake: at the end of the line, I used space instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Is there any VBScript to automatically shift 'Enter's at the end of line? If any, please let me know.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. Please provide an example of what your text looks like an how you want it to look like.

Comment: You can search and replace. Use ` ^p` for find and `^l` for replace.

Comment: Sir, iam giving correct example i have text in ms word at the end of each line there is space but i need shift + enter so is there any vbscript?

Comment: You didn't give an example at all. Please *show* sample text (or at least a screenshot) that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: It would be possible, but given your situation writing the code would not be trivial. Word cannot search for "end of the line" and "lines" are not part of the object model. If you read the [help] guidelines for asking on Stack Overflow you'll note that this is not a code-writing or tutorial service.